# Coding Lemoine's Conjecture in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to code a function that when given N, will return a pair of numbers that comply with Lemoine's Conjecture (every odd number greater than 5 can be expressed as the sum of a prime and the double of a prime). I have created this code based on a previous function relating to Goldbach's Conjecture (this function works fine) and have used a different function to generate a list of prime numbers up to N, however my new code isn't giving me correct results and I can't see why- any ideas? Thanks

```
def eratosthenes2(n):
     primes = list (range(2, n+1))
     for i in primes:
        j=2
        while i*j<+ primes[-1]:
            if i*j in primes:
                primes.remove(i*j)
            j=j+1
    return primes

def lemoine(N):
    x, y = 0, 0
    result = 0
    if N % 2:
        prime = eratosthenes2(N)
        while result != N:
            for i in range(len(prime)):
                x = prime[i]
                if result == N: 
                    break
                for j in range(len(prime)):
                    y = prime[j]
                    result = 2*x + y
                    if result == N: 
                        break 
    return x, y
```

Comment: modifying a list while iterating over it is usually a bad idea. Your `eratosthenes2()` is very slow since deleting elements from the middle of a list is inefficient. Why not just *mark* composite elements and then get the final list at the end? In addition to being slow, it simply doesn't work, certifying many composite numbers as prime. Why not debug that function prior to writing another function that depends on it?

Comment: Hi John, this is for a uni project and, as you can probably tell, I'm not great at coding. We've been told to do it a certain way so, while it is not hugely efficient, it's going to have to stay I'm afraid! You mentioned that the eratosthenes function doesn't work; would you mind pointing out where exactly I'm going wrong? I have altered the range to (3,n) as I only want odd primes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have to use the sieve method, then first:

Change your sieve to use `n` instead of `n + 1`:

```
primes = list (range(2, n))
```

Next, change your `lemoine` function to have:

```
if result == N:                             
    return x, y
```

instead of the current way, where you `break` when `result == N`. The way you have it now, you're exiting the function after `x` has been incremented one more time, leading to incorrect results. (e.g. `2` instead of `3` in the below `n = 47` example.

Here's a working implementation to compare with:

```
def isPrime (n):
  if n < 2:
    return False

  for i in range(2, (int(n ** (1/2)) + 1)):
    if n % i == 0:
      return False
  return True

def lemoine(n):
  pairs = {}

  # n = p + (2 * q)
  for q in range(1, int(n / 2)):
    p = n - 2 * q

    # Are p and q prime?
    if isPrime(p) and isPrime(q):
      pairs[p] = q

  return pairs

n = 47
pairs = lemoine(n)
for key in pairs:
  print('{} is {} + 2 * {}'.format(n, key, pairs[key]))
```

This gives the output:

```
47 is 43 + 2 * 2
47 is 41 + 2 * 3
47 is 37 + 2 * 5
47 is 13 + 2 * 17
```

This example is from [the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemoine%27s_conjecture).

Comment: Side Note: the range in `isPrime` should be `range(2, int(n ** (1/2)) + 1)` since `range` has an open-interval on the right (as well as the point that `n ** 1/2` will evaluate to `(n ** 1) / 2`.